# PostMessage from WorkerThread to Main Window in MFC

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, mfc, postmessage, worker-thread

I have a MFC application, which has a worker thread, what I want to do is to post message from worker  thread to the Main GUI thread to update some status messages on GUI. What I have done so far is `Registered a new window message`

```
//custom messages
static UINT FTP_APP_STATUS_UPDATE = ::RegisterWindowMessageA("FTP_APP_STATUS_UPDATE");
```

Added this message to the message map of dialog class

```
ON_MESSAGE(FTP_APP_STATUS_UPDATE, &CMFC_TestApplicationDlg::OnStatusUpdate)
```

The prototype of `OnStatusUpdate` is

```
afx_msg LRESULT OnStatusUpdate(WPARAM, LPARAM);
```

and definition is

```
LRESULT CMFC_TestApplicationDlg::OnStatusUpdate(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

     //This function is not called at all.
     return 0;
}
```

and the worker thread calling code is

```
void CMFC_TestApplicationDlg::OnBnClickedMfcbutton1()
{
    ThreadParams params;
    params.m_hWnd = m_hWnd;
    params.FTPHost = "test_host";
    params.FTPUsername = "test";
    params.FTPPassword = "test";

    AfxBeginThread(FTPConnectThread,&params);
}
```

and Worker thread code is

```
//child thread function
UINT FTPConnectThread( LPVOID pParam )
{
    if(pParam == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    ThreadParams *params = (ThreadParams*)pParam;
    OutputDebugString(params->FTPHost);
    Sleep(4000); //simulating a network call
    CString * message = new CString("Conencted");
    PostMessage(params->m_hWnd,FTP_APP_STATUS_UPDATE,0,(LPARAM)message);
    //PostMessage do nothing? what I am doing wrong?
    return 1;
}
```

the problem is when the PostMessage function is called the `OnStatusUpdate` should be called, but it is not being called, no exception or assertion is thrown, What I am doing wrong? I have tried `ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE` and `ON_MESSAGE` but no success, any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CMFC_TestApplicationDlg::OnBnClickedMfcbutton1()` may return before the thread starts. This causes your `ThreadParams` to go out of scope, so when you access it from the thread, you are accessing freed memory. You need to allocate it some other way, such as:

```
void CMFC_TestApplicationDlg::OnBnClickedMfcbutton1()
{
    ThreadParams* params = new ThreadParams();
    params->m_hWnd = m_hWnd;
    params->FTPHost = "test_host";
    params->FTPUsername = "test";
    params->FTPPassword = "test";

    AfxBeginThread(FTPConnectThread,params);
}

//child thread function
UINT FTPConnectThread( LPVOID pParam )
{
    if(pParam == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ThreadParams *params = (ThreadParams*)pParam;
    OutputDebugString(params->FTPHost);
    Sleep(4000); //simulating a network call
    CString * message = new CString("Conencted");
    PostMessage(params->m_hWnd,FTP_APP_STATUS_UPDATE,0,(LPARAM)message);

    delete params;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, your code with a minor change worked, It worked when I used it with `ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE`